# Zen Load Balancer HTTPS to HTTPS

Tags: ssl, load-balancing, https, pound

I've been struggling with an issue that I am hoping someone can help with. Basically, I have setup a working Zen Load Balancer going from HTTPS to HTTP but I am struggling with getting it to work using HTTPS on both sides. When I configure HTTPS to HTTPS I get the following error messages in the syslog:

```
Jul 19 15:13:28 zenbal01 pound: (b730cb70) e500 can't read header
Jul 19 15:13:28 zenbal01 pound: (b730cb70) e500 response error read from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The LB and the backend server has the same certificates installed so the SSL handshake should match.

Has anyone else gotten this to work or have any advice on what can be done to get the handshake to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In ZEn Load Balancer v3.02 or less you can't configure a HTTPS farm with HTTPS backends, (not supported). If you need this support then use TCP or L4 farms, the entire communication will go through the load balancer in raw mode

I Hope this help you